# ssh login works but sftp does not

Tags: ssh, sftp

I can use ssh to login-in Centos by Xshell, but I can not download files from Centos by FileZilla. I have tried to login-in in different network or computer, the result is still the same. However, when I tried to use my colleagues' account, it works well. So, I think there is something wrong with the configuration of sftp.
With google's help, I want to find some hints form the debug info of sftp login by:

```
sftp -vvvv linxingzhong@192.168.1.224


OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.224 [192.168.1.224] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.224" from file "/home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1575/3072
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 9e:52:8f:3e:34:08:02:ae:cc:a1:cb:5f:d4:52:63:33
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.224" from file "/home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.1.224' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1548/3072
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 24 padlen 8 extra_pad 64)
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 10 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.224 ([192.168.1.224]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
```

When I typed password, it got stuck, and I can not get any useful messages.

In configure file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
    CheckHostIP             no  
    ForwardX11              yes  
    ForwardAgent        yes  
    StrictHostKeyChecking   no  
    UsePrivilegedPort       no  
    Protocol        2,1  
    HostbasedAuthentication yes  
    EnableSSHKeySign        yes
```

I also tried to `scp` files:

```
scp -vvvv workspace/file.list linxingzhong@192.168.1.224:/lustre/project/og02/linxingzhong/projects/  

Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.224, user linxingzhong, command scp -v -t /lustre/project/og02/linxingzhong/projects/  
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013  
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *  
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.224 [192.168.1.224] port 22.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1  
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3  
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000  
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.224" from file "/home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys  
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0   
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0   
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5  
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none  
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5  
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none  
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16  
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP   
debug2: bits set: 1510/3072  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY  
debug1: Server host key: RSA 9e:52:8f:3e:34:08:02:ae:cc:a1:cb:5f:d4:52:63:33  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.224" from file "/home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys  
debug1: Host '192.168.1.224' is known and matches the RSA host key.  
debug1: Found key in /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
debug2: bits set: 1529/3072  
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct  
debug2: kex_derive_keys  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent  
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),  
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),  
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),  
debug2: key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased  
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased  
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex  
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex  
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex   
debug1: No valid Key exchange context   
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic  
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic  
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic  
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available  

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
No Kerberos credentials available  

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
No Kerberos credentials available  

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey  
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey  
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa  
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory  
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa  
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory  
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa  
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory  
debug1: Trying private key: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519  
debug3: no such identity: /home/linxingzhong/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory  
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive  
debug3: remaining preferred: password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive  
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive  
debug2: userauth_kbdint  
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1  
Password:   
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 24 padlen 8 extra_pad 64)  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0  
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 10 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)  
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).  
Authenticated to 192.168.1.224 ([192.168.1.224]:22).  
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK  
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK  
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]  
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0  
debug2: channel 0: send open  
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com  
debug1: Entering interactive session.   
debug2: callback start    
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY  
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08  
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0  
debug1: Sending environment.  
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID  
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME  
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED  
debug3: Ignored env TERM  
debug3: Ignored env SHELL  
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE  
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT  
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE  
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY  
debug3: Ignored env USER   
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH  
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS  
debug3: Ignored env MAIL  
debug3: Ignored env PATH  
debug3: Ignored env PWD  
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8  
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0  
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED  
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL  
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL  
debug3: Ignored env HOME  
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME  
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION  
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN   
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR  
debug3: Ignored env _  
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /lustre/project/og02/linxingzhong/projects/  
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1   
debug2: callback done  
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768  
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152  
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0  
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: You can add more `v`s to get more verbose output.

Comment: In your `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` file, do you see a sftp subsytem override ? A line like this `Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` and it should be uncommented for sftp to work. Executable location might vary.

Comment: @John Oliver, I've pasted the message after adding more `v` as your suggesstion.

Comment: @ MelBurslan, /etc/ssh/sshd.conf does not exit, there is a `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead.

Comment: @l0o0 the `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` file is on the server you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Perhaps you do not have some permission on remote server. Please, check on remote server if you and some *working* colleague of yours are in the same groups (using `groups` command).

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! To mark a question as solved, simply accept the correct answer. Do _not_ modify your title to include something like "SOLVED". If there is no correct answer, put the solution into a new answer and mark it as accepted. Answering your own questions is [explicitly encouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Dubu, Thank you for your notification. ;)

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED to question titles. The standard way of marking a question as answered/solved is selecting the right answer. You will notice a green box appears next to the question after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ssh-login-works-but-sftp-doesn't-369380/) is the same problem. I found one line in my bashrc.

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nfs3/onegene/user/group1/linxingzhong/opt/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
#export PATH=/nfs2/pipe/RNA/soft/R-3.1.2/bin/R:$PATH
#export R_HOME=/nfs2/pipe/RNA/soft/R-3.1.2/
#export R_USER=linxinzhong
export PATH=/export/home/linxingzhong/opt/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/nfs3/onegene/user/group1/linxingzhong/opt/bin:$PATH
#export PATH=$PATH:/nfs2/pipe/RNA/soft/R-3.1.2/bin
export PYTHONPATH=/nfs3/onegene/user/group1/linxingzhong/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
alias tmux='tmux -2'
#export R_LIBS=/nfs3/onegene/user/group1/linxingzhong/opt/R-packages
export R_LIBS=/nfs3/onegene/user/group1/linxingzhong/opt/R-packages
#[ -f $HOME/opt/bin/zsh ] && exec $HOME/opt/bin/zsh -l
zsh
```

After I remove the last line, I can connect to the sftp.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you tried to use your colleague's account which works, and if you
   mean to say that you tried your colleague's account on your machine,
   using the same syntax as you tried with your own account, than the
   problem is likely that you are lacking permissions on whatever you
   are trying to access.

Also looking at the output from sftp:

> debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

"needpriv 0" tells you that your connecting ssh client has no local privilege and will therefore use a TCP port above 1023 for the outgoing connection.

2. You can also try to use scp (if available), and see if it allows you to transfer the file (may also help indicate any permission issues)

Comment: `scp` doesn't work as well. I've pasted the messages above. Thank you for your reply