# I can SFTP but not SSH

Tags: ssh, sftp

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268440/ssh-login-works-but-sftp-does-not) is similiar, but I'm experiencing the reverse scenario. **SFTP** works but I'm not yet connected using **SSH**.

I'm using a `config` file and I'm able to sftp to remote server.
Local machine is on linux and remote server is CentOS.

```
sftp foobar_remote

config
Host foobar_remote

  HostName foobar.biz
  Port 2222
  User bizz
  IdentityFile local/bizzbuzz/id_rsa
```

On my local machine, I'm in the same directory as `id_rsa`

```
ssh -i id_rsa bizz@foobar.biz
```

I still get prompted for **bizz@foobar.biz** password.

**After Responding to Comments**

I'm using a different key (id_rsa) now, and I no longer get promted for a password.
Now, I get the following response

```
Welcome to foobar.biz
shell request failed on chananel 0
```

Comment: are you sure you use exact same private key ? local/bizzbuzz/id_rsa vs id_rsa ? you may also use ssh -vvv to have a very hairy log session and see which private key was (or wasn't) fetch.

Comment: That seems to help. I'm getting a new error now, which I've added to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sftp` and `ssh` connect to the same `sshd`.  If you can *connect* with one, you can with the other.  The difference is what program `sshd` invokes, **sftp-server(8)** or your login shell.

I suspect your login shell is not installed or not allowed on the remote machine.  **shell request failed** sounds a lot like `execvp(shell, args)` returned an error.

To test, try invoking some other known executable and your shell explicitly,

```
$ ssh remote /bin/date
$ ssh remote /usr/bin/bash # or whatever
```

If one works and the other fails, you've isolated your problem.

Comment: "...or not allowed on the remote machine"  The sysadmins have disabled ssh allowing, of the two, only sftp.